# How to use a Page variable in User Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, postback

I have a page with a private variable: `AccountData`.

This handles all of the account data and I save it in the *viewstate* between postbacks.
I have a User Control named `AccountFavorites` that renders all of the account Favorite topics.

When a user decides he wants to cancel one favorite topic he clicks on an `asp:LinkButton` and it posts back to the server to change the value in the Database.

However, the Control doesn't know what `AccountData` is, only the page does.

How can I use the `AccountData` in a postback of the Control?

Can I make the postback go to the page instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is page that owns/parents the user control, it is preferable to for the page to know about the specifics of the control, not the other way around. Add `AccountData` property to the control and in the page's `Page_Load` do:

```
uc.AccountData = AccountData;
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't I need to add it to the ViewState of the Control as well? or can you offer another idea?

Comment: No, you don't need it in the control's ViewState. The control will use the same instance as the page. You have to make sure that the above assignment happens after the page reads AccountData from the page's ViewState. Also, in the control code, add precautions against AccountData being null (not set).

Comment: Thanks @Igor, this has helped me a lot.
Just one more question if you may, my Control is in a ListView in the Page. this means that on every Postback I will have to re-bind it, right?

Comment: If by "re-bind" you mean "execute the above assignment" - then yes.

Comment: @Bergkamp If you add it to the controls `ViewState` then you won't have to "rebind" every time.

Comment: @mason, but is wise to fill up the viewState? won't it make the page "heavy"?

Comment: Not only is it not wise, but after the first postback, you will have two instances of AccountData - one referenced by the page and the other referenced by the control. This will lead to interesting and exciting debugging.

Comment: well, thank you both guys. You both helped me. I will go with @Igor's response. by the way I have changed the control and it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

```
<myprefix:AccountFavorites runat="server" id="TheAccountFavorites" />
```

In your page set the info...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TheAccountFavorites.TheAccountData=MyAccountData;//assuming you'll load up MyAccountData
}
```

In your control, expose AccountData as a public property. This will allow you to access it from the page.

```
public AccountData TheAccountData {get;set;}
```

This is assuming `AccountData` was the type name and not something else, like a string. But you can change AccountData to string and it will work.